# SharePoint User Specific Key Value settings

Tags: 2010, 2007, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I need to create functionality to save user specific data like bookmark, favorites etc. I want to know about the best approach I can take to save the user specific data so that logged in user can see their settings like we can use Property Bags to store site/web specific data.

Regards,

Ashish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you want to make them reusable across the site collection for each
>   user you can add Fields to the User Information List. You can add a
>   feature receiver to your web parts solution that can create this
>   column or check to see if this column exists in the User information
>   list to be sure that the Column exists.
>
> The User Information list is a Standard SharePoint list that
>   SharePoint uses to store user information.  To access the User
>   Information List you can go to the Root web of the Site Collection and
>   use the SiteUserInfoList property
>
> E.G.
>
> ```
> SPList userInformationlist = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.SiteUserInfoList;
> //Or 
> SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb;
> SPList userInformationlist = web.SiteUserInfoList;
> ```
>
> To access a users List Item you can use the Users Id to get the
>   ListItem back from the User Information List
>
> E.G.
>
> ```
> SPListItem currentUserItem = userInformationlist.GetItemById(web.CurrentUser.ID);
> ```
>
> If you are using MOSS you can store this information in the User
>   Profiles and make it available across Site Collections this does not
>   need My Sites to be enabled. You would need to use the User Profile
>   classes to access this.

Fore More Information [how-to-store-user-specific-data-in-sharepoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756696/how-to-store-user-specific-data-in-sharepoint)